# NEo4j Query Result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I started learning Neo4j Cypher. I am using Neo4j Sample Movie Graph Database.

Below is the Cypher I've written expecting Cypher to return the result 1964, but it's returning a NULL value.

```
MATCH (tom:Person) where tom.Name ="Tom Hanks" return tom.born;
```

Going through Neo4j Tutorial I found that Relationship is having property. When I run the below query it also results in NULL, whereas I am expecting Relationship "ACTED_IN" is having property role, so it should return the value "role".

```
match (:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[rel]->(M) RETURN M.title,rel.property;
```

Comment: MATCH (per:Person {Name:"Tom Hanks"}) return per.born; also written cypher to get born year for Tom Hanks but query return null. But when I am writing Reverse cypher i.e. Giving born year and able to fetch name. here is cypher MATCH (per:Person {born:1964}) return per.name;. So Why I am Getting NULL when I am writing Name try to find out year of born.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are case sensitive. You are using `Name` when the property is `name`. Try:

```
MATCH (tom:Person) WHERE tom.name = "Tom Hanks" RETURN tom.born;
```

For the other query, `property` is not a property on the `:ACTED_IN` relationship. It is called `roles`. Try:

```
MATCH (:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[rel]->(M) 
RETURN M.title, rel.roles;
```

If you want the keys of the properties on that relationship:

```
MATCH (:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[rel]->(M) 
RETURN M.title, KEYS(rel);
```